# What's the difference between following two mongodb queries?

Tags: mongodb

I ran following two queries and they returned different results.

```sh
// my query 1
> db.events.count({"startTimeUnix":{$lt:1533268800000},"startTimeUnix":{$gte:1533182400000}})
131
// existing app query 2
> db.events.count({"startTimeUnix":{"$lt":1533268800000,"$gte":1533182400000}})
0
```

The query 2 is already being used in the batch application but it reported to pulling less records which I confirmed from these queries.

```sh
//these counts are confusing
> db.events.count()
2781
> db.events.count({"startTimeUnix":{$lt:1533268800000}})
361
> db.events.count({"startTimeUnix":{$gte:1533182400000}})
2780
```

Comment: what does `db.events.count({"startTimeUnix":"$lt":1533268800000}})` return?

Comment: @Naya I updated the Q with the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the second query.  You can add explain() to find out the query plans.  The first query

```
db.events.count({"startTimeUnix":{$lt:1533268800000},"startTimeUnix":{$gte:1533182400000}})
```

is evaluated the same as

```
db.events.explain().count({"startTimeUnix":{$gte:1533182400000}})
```

Use the command below to view the query plans.

```
db.events.explain().count({"startTimeUnix":{$lt:1533268800000},"startTimeUnix":{$gte:1533182400000}})
```

Answer (score 1):

query 2 is an impicit (and proper) way of building [AND condition](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#and-queries-with-multiple-expressions-specifying-the-same-field), query 1 is incorrect in terms of MongoDB syntax. The way it gets analyzed is pretty simple, MongoDB takes first condtion and then overrides it with second one so it has the same meaning as:

```
db.events.count({"startTimeUnix":{$gte:1533182400000}})
```

first condition simply gets ignored and that's why you're getting more results (described [here](http://christophermaier.name/2010/12/21/mongodb-query-tricks/))

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that mongo doesn't parse operators if the are in quotes.
db.events.count({"startTimeUnix":{"$lt":1533268800000,"$gte":1533182400000}})
means that it looks for the entries where startTimeUnix is an object and contains fields "$lt" and "$gte" 
If you'll the next command, this query starts returning 1:

```
db.events.insert({"startTimeUnix":{"$lt":1533268800000,"$gte":1533182400000}})
```